# How to manage overlapping bar and drawer in React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have five screens in a material bottom tab navigator. On one of the screens, I want to use a drawer for some settings. In the other screens there are currently no drawers planned, however if they come, they will have different content from this current one.

I want the drawer to be displayed above the bottom navigation bar. However I don't want to solve it by wrapping the whole material bottom tab navigator in a drawer navigator, as this would not make much sense and also provide the same drawer in all of the screens.

Is there another way of making the drawer appear on top of the bottom navigation bar? Ideally, the solution would not include react-navigation for the drawer at all, as I don't use it for navigation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be to use a Modal, which can server as a popup. https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal for the documentation.